# remove single quote from string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have string as output from a soap service and string has single quote `'` inside the xml elements like below

```
<Tracking diffgr:id="Tracking311" msdata:rowOrder="310">
                            <rowId>736729953</rowId>
                            <awbNo>290349641723</awbNo>
                            <Date>12 Oct 2022 13:32</Date>
                            <Activity>OUT FOR DELIVERY</Activity>
                            <Details>Ha'il</Details>
                            <Location>Ha'il</Location>
                            <scanCode>OFD</scanCode>
 </Tracking>
```

i am trying to replace single quote `'` from details and location tag. if the the above string is passed to `replace` function the query is not parsed as its not a complete string.

```
select REPLACE('<Tracking diffgr:id="Tracking311" msdata:rowOrder="310">
                            <rowId>736729953</rowId>
                            <awbNo>290349641723</awbNo>
                            <Date>12 Oct 2022 13:32</Date>
                            <Activity>OUT FOR DELIVERY</Activity>
                            <Details>Ha'il</Details>
                            <Location>Ha'il</Location>
                            <scanCode>OFD</scanCode>
                        </Tracking>',chr(39),'') from dual
```

above query is showing simple error `[Error] Execution (45: 41): ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: For manually created queries you may use q-quotrd [text literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA). For external data use binf variables or static SQL statements with PL/SQL variables.

Answer (score 0):

The string you have has a single quote in, so Oracle sees it as the end of the string, and that's why you get the error.

You can do this:

```
select REPLACE('<Tracking diffgr:id="Tracking311" msdata:rowOrder="310">
                        <rowId>736729953</rowId>
                        <awbNo>290349641723</awbNo>
                        <Date>12 Oct 2022 13:32</Date>
                        <Activity>OUT FOR DELIVERY</Activity>
                        <Details>Ha''il</Details>
                        <Location>Ha''il</Location>
                        <scanCode>OFD</scanCode>
                    </Tracking>',chr(39),'') from dual;
```

If you want to remove the quotes from the column during the SELECT, just do:

```
select REPLACE(column_name,chr(39),'') from dual;
```

Comment: i am getting in string from the webservice , so i have to parse the response right after receive , i am not storing the response into a column

Comment: So you're building your SQL statement based on outside data? And then having a program doing the inserts? Then you should be using bind variables. What language are you using?

Comment: i am using plsql based on outisde data as response from webservice